# Capistrano complains there are too few arguments but it doesn't say what it's referring to

Tags: capistrano

I've been bug solving all morning but I've run into something I'm unable to solve. Capistrano is throwing this message:

```
cap aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:14:in `invoke'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:14:in `block in after'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => deploy
The deploy has failed with an error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

Any idea what it's even referring to?

You can see all of the output of running `cap production deploy` [here](https://gist.github.com/Arcrammer/c21701bb727521f5459e).

`Deploy.rb`, `Production.rb`, and `Capfile` are [here](https://gist.github.com/Arcrammer/773ac165f54c5e387417).

Answer (score 0):

I had both Capistrano 2 and 3 installed on my machine. Uninstalling both of those gems then installing only the version I needed allowed a successful deploy!